# npm install not generating package lock for workspace

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node monorepo with several workspaces. I'm in the process of adding a new workspace and it seems that npm won't generate a package-lock.json file for the new workspace. However, npm has no problem regenerating lock files for the other workspaces.

I've tried running `npm install --package-lock-only`, I've tried checking for an `.npmrc` in my monorepo which may have set `package-lock false` and I've tried running the following

```
 ❯❯❯ npm config set package-lock true
npm WARN config This command does not support workspaces.
```

from the workspace.

Why might npm be refusing to generate a package-lock.json for this particular workspace of mine? How can I force npm to generate a lockfile for this workspace (in addition to all the other lockfiles in the monorepo)?

Comment: `npm install --package-lock-only` should really give a nice error/warning why it can't generate a lockfile :(